# Recuperar variable $_SESSION en DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

quiero que me ayuden con lo siguiente:

1. Tengo un archivo que se llama gestionar-mis-reportes-geo.php, este archivo me deberá de mostrar los registros que previamente he realizado en el sistema (Los registros se hacen de forma correcta), el problema esta cuando voy a consultarlos de forma dinámica y estoy utilizando Ajax para que sea de forma más rápida, pero a la hora de abrir la vista con el nombre anteriormente mencionado, me arroja un error.

El archivo gestionar-mis-reporte-geo.php contiene el siguiente codigo:

```
    <div class="preloader flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img class="animation__shake" src="dist/img/logo2.png" height="60" width="60">
    </div>

    <?php
    include 'frontend/barra_superior.php';
    include 'frontend/menu.php';
    ?>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0">Gestionar Mis Reportes</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Georreferenciación</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Mis Reportes</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Contenido Principal -->
        <?php
        include 'frontend/contenido_principal.php';

        $key = "j458t74544sd_yti5487o54q6112we_ty8u86w4e8445we";
        $documento = $_SESSION['idusuario'];

        $consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT a.idasignacion_geo idasignacion_geo, u.documento documento, u.nombre1 nombre1, u.nombre2 nombre2,
        u.apellido1 apellido1, u.apellido2 apellido2, u.telefono telefono, u.correo correo, a.detalle_asignacion detalle FROM asignacion_geo a
        INNER JOIN usuario u ON a.fk_usuario = u.documento WHERE u.documento = '$documento'");

        $row = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

        if ($row == null || $row == 0) { ?>
            <script language="javascript">
                alert("ERROR / NO ESTA AUTORIZADO PARA REPORTAR INFORMACION DE GEORREFERENCIACION");
                window.location.href = "index";
            </script>;
        <?php }
        ?>

        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="card card-primary">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h3 class="card-title">Mis Reportes de Georreferenciación</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table id="table_ajax" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr align="center">
                                            <th>FECHA</th>
                                            <th>DOCUMENTO</th>
                                            <th>NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS</th>
                                            <th>BARRIO</th>
                                            <th>ESTADO VIVIENDA</th>
                                            <th>SUSCEPTIBLE COVID-19 ADULTOS</th>
                                            <th>CANTIDAD ADULTOS</th>
                                            <th>SUSCEPTIBLE SARAMPIÓN Y RUBÉOLA</th>
                                            <th>CANTIDAD NIÑOS</th>
                                            <th>SINTOMÁTICOS RESPIRATORIOS</th>
                                            <th>ACCIÓN</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
</div>

<?php
include 'frontend/footer.php';
?>
</div>

<?php
include 'frontend/scripts.php';
?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#table_ajax").DataTable({
            "sAjaxSource": "consultas_ajax/sql_reportes_geo.php",
            "aoColumns": [{
                    mData: 'fecha'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'documento'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'nombres'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'barrio'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'estado_vivienda'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'pocovid_adulto'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'cant_adulto'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'posarampion_rubeola'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'cant_ninos'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'sintomatico_respiratorio'
                },
                {
                    mData: 'accion'
                },
            ],
            retrieve: true,
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            "pageLength": 10,
            "order": [
                [1, "asc"]
            ],
            "columnDefs": [{
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true,
            }],
            "responsive": true,
            "paging": true,
            "searching": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "stateSave": true,
            //"buttons": ["excel", "pdf", "colvis"],
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'excel', 'pdf', 'print', "colvis"
            ]
        }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
    });
</script>
```

El otro archivo al cual estoy accediendo con una consulta se llama sql_reportes_geo.php y tiene el siguiente código:

```
$u_documento = $_SESSION['idusuario'];

$sql = "SELECT d.iddata_georreferenciacion idgeo, d.coordenadas coordenadas, b.idbarrio idbarrio, b.nombre barrio,
d.documento documento, d.nombres nombres, d.apellidos apellidos, e.idestado_vivienda idestado_vivienda, 
e.nombre estado_vivienda, pa.idpocovid_adulto idpocovid_adulto, pa.nombre pocovid_adulto, d.cant_adultos cant_adulto,
ps.idsarampion_rubeola idsarampion_rubeola, ps.nombre po_sarampion_rubeola, d.cant_menores cant_ninos,
pr.idsintomatico_respiratorio idsintomatico, pr.nombre sintomatico_respiratorio, u.documento u_documento, 
d.fecha_reporte fecha_reporte, d.hora_reporte hora_reporte 
FROM data_georreferenciacion d
INNER JOIN barrio b ON d.fk_barrio = b.idbarrio
INNER JOIN estado_vivienda e ON d.fk_estado_vivienda = e.idestado_vivienda
INNER JOIN po_covid_adulto pa ON d.fk_pocovid_adulto = pa.idpocovid_adulto
INNER JOIN po_sarampion_rubeola ps ON d.fk_posarampion_rubeola = ps.idsarampion_rubeola
INNER JOIN po_sintomatico_respiratorio pr ON d.fk_posintomatica_res = pr.idsintomatico_respiratorio
INNER JOIN usuario u ON d.fk_usuario = u.documento
WHERE u.documento = '$u_documento'";
```

A la hora de realizar la consulta, me genera error, alguien que me ayude por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder a la información de las variables guardadas en sesión se debe invocar primero a la función session_start().
Todas las páginas que guarden o lean datos de $_SESSION deben comenzar con la función session_start().

Espero te sirva. Saludos.